# KVM Virt Manager + SPICE

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I am trying to get **SPICE-agent** to work properly on a ***KVM Virtual Machine*** so I can share folders or copy paste from host to VM.  I get this error when I try to enable it, even though I installed spice-agent on the host also.

```
Error starting domain, internal error
QEMU: host doesn’t support expected feature (MSR-490h)
```

```
Error starting domain: internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2022-03-04T06:58:42.186263Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]
2022-03-04T06:58:42.186761Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]
2022-03-04T06:58:42.186769Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]
2022-03-04T06:58:42.187275Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]
2022-03-04T06:58:42.187282Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]
2022-03-04T06:58:42.225769Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device virtio-9p-pci,id=fs0,fsdev=fsdev-fs0,mount_tag=/sharepoint,bus=pci.7,addr=0x0: cannot initialize fsdev 'fsdev-fs0': failed to open '/home/a/share': Permission denied
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 75, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 111, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 66, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1279, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1234, in create
    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2022-03-04T06:58:42.186263Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]
2022-03-04T06:58:42.186761Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]
2022-03-04T06:58:42.186769Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]
2022-03-04T06:58:42.187275Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]
2022-03-04T06:58:42.187282Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]
2022-03-04T06:58:42.225769Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device virtio-9p-pci,id=fs0,fsdev=fsdev-fs0,mount_tag=/sharepoint,bus=pci.7,addr=0x0: cannot initialize fsdev 'fsdev-fs0': failed to open '/home/a/share': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the relevant part of the error message is this: `failed to open '/home/a/share': Permission denied`

Check if that directory exists and if it permits qemu access.